# Can the harmonic series be assigned a shift invariant value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have seen a treatment (I cannot remember where from) that treats the whole $-\frac{1}{12}$ business as follows. We define a summation function $ \sum :A \to F$ via the following axioms:

1) $F$ is a field

2) $A \subseteq F^{\mathbb Z ^+}$

3) $ \sum a_n = a_1 + \sum a_{n+1}$

4) $\sum$ is linear

Now it's not too hard too show that (over the real field) $\sum 1$ cannot be defined, and hence that $ \sum n$ cannot be defined.

Now I've been looking through proofs of the harmonic series divergences, eg here http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf
I've noticed that all the proofs either rebracket the sum some way or use some sort of inequality.

My question is whether, given my axioms it is possible to assign a value to $\sum \frac1n$. Now if I try to just assign it a value I end up having to assign a value to $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, and $\sum \frac{n^2+2n+2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$ and so on. So I am not quite sure whether I will eventually come up with a contradiction or not.

edit: 
Some people in the comments have linked me to a MO question that is similar, and I've pick up a bit of terminology. So I guess what I am asking is whether the harmonic series can be assigned a shift invariant value.

Comment: I asked a version of this question 10 years ago on MO! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3204/does-any-method-of-summing-divergent-series-work-on-the-harmonic-series

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You didn't answer to my point. Summation methods = replacing $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ by $\lim_{t \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n f_n(t)$. Of course with $f_n(t) =e^{-nt}$ and $f_n(t)= n^{-t}$ we get easy to formalize shift and scale invariance, but there are much more possible regulators and with $a_n = 1/n$ it diverges only for the most common ones.

Comment: @reuns I've looked through your answer, and its not obvious to me that $ \lim\limits_{t \to 1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-t^3} \cos ( t \ln n) a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ due to the oscillatory behaviour of cosine and assuming you meant sometime similar to my third axiom by shift invariance, it is not obvious to me that that holds either.

Comment: @B.Martin $\lim\limits_{t \to \color{red}{0}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-t^3} \cos ( t \ln n) a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ when $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$, what do you expect more ? The shift invariance (that if $a_1=0$ then $sum (a_n) = sum (a_{n+1})$) is very rare in summation methods.